# How to use to_sql method to fill table with column with point datatype using postgresql and pandas?

Tags: postgresql, pandas

I have a Excel with many columns. Two columns from that are Latitude and Longitude. I need to import the data from excel to a table in PostgreSQL using Pandas. The table in PG has one column instead of two.The one column has name Coordinate and it's type is *POINT*.

For example, the excel data contains:

```
Name        Longitude       Latitude
MEDELLÍN    -75.5760017134  6.24858636743
ABEJORRAL   -75.4287403904  5.78930111433
ABRIAQUÍ    -76.0642948678  6.63228195504
ALEJANDRÍA  -75.141334501   6.37606264274
```

And I want to import the data using Pandas as a PostgreSQL table:

```
Name        Position
MEDELLÍN    POINT(-75.5760017134,6.24858636743)
ABEJORRAL   POINT(-75.4287403904,5.78930111433)
ABRIAQUÍ    POINT(-76.0642948678,6.63228195504)
ALEJANDRÍA  POINT(-75.141334501,6.37606264274)
```

*How can i "concatenate" the two source columns (Lat and Lon) and import the data to PostgreSQL using the method to_sql?*

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where's your sample data?

Comment: do you have postgis extension?  You can use `ST_MakePoint(long, lat)` to make a point before insert operation

Comment: @cmaher I don't know what try first. And Edited the question with sample data.

Comment: @Krishna and the function to_sql from panda's dataframe supports using ST_MakePoint?

Comment: @Krishna And actually, I don't use postgis, only native POINT datatype.

Comment: SO isn't a code-writing service, so you really need to make an attempt at this task yourself first. Try to get one step working at a time -- your first step is to figure out how to read your Excel data into a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: Yeah, i wasn't clear. I have the data in a dataframe, but I  don't know how to convert the two double columns to one Point column and send it to Postgres. I  will be clearer in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have `psycopg2, pandas, geopandas` libraries installed. First you import your csv file to `pandas` dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
from shapely.geometry import Point
import psycopg2

df = pd.read_table('./sample.csv', sep=',', header='infer')
```

Convert `lat/long` to `Point` type with some spatial reference (I am using `EPSG 4236`) and drop `lat/long` columns because you will only be uploading `name, Point` columns.

```
geom = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.Longitude, df.Latitude)]
df = df.drop(['Longitude', 'Latitude'], axis=1)
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
gdf = GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geom)
```

`gdf.head()` results

```
    Name        geometry
0   MEDELLÍN    POINT (-75.5760017134 6.248586367430001)
1   ABEJORRAL   POINT (-75.42874039039999 5.789301114330001)
2   ABRIAQUÍ    POINT (-76.0642948678 6.632281955040001)
3   ALEJANDRÍA  POINT (-75.141334501 6.376062642740001)
```

Now you are ready to upload to `postgres`. Create a connection to postgres

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='template1' user='dbuser' host='localhost' password='dbpass'")
gdf.to_sql(`your_table_name`, conn, other options)
```

See version specific `pandas` documentation for further details on `to_sql`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your answer and I will back later.

Comment: Sorry, but i have one question, do I need postgis to use geopandas with postgres? can i use a column with native POINT datatype?

Comment: @gabomgp you do not. `geopandas` library takes care of `lat/long` to `Point` conversion. You'll need `postgis` to make spatial queries on database side.